# Express Session Cookie (connect.sid) not being deleted from browser after destroying session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I have a Vue.js SPA and a Node.js API built with Express.js. I'm using express-session (^1.11.3)  to manage sessions and express-sequelize-session (0.4.0) to persist the session on a Postgres DB through Sequelize because I need a session to be able to use passport-azure-ad with oidc strategy.

I was having some issues logging in with Microsoft accounts after some time and came to the conclusion that it is because the session cookie (connect.sid) is never cleared from the browser.

I had some things misconfigured and made some changes but even with all the changes it is still not working.

Session on my Express app is configured in the following way:

```js
import session from 'express-session';
import expressSequelizeSession from 'express-sequelize-session';

const Store = expressSequelizeSession(session.Store);

app.use(session({
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: env !== 'development', // On environments that have SSL enable this should be set to true.
    maxAge: null,
    sameSite: false, // Needs to be false otherwise Microsoft auth doesn't work.
  },
  secret: config.secrets.session,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  unset: 'destroy',
  store: new Store(sqldb.sequelize),
}));
```

On the FE I'm using Vue.js with Axios and setting withCredentials to true so that the cookie is passed on the HTTP request.

```js
// Base configuration.
import Axios from 'axios';

Axios.defaults.baseURL = config.apiURL;
Axios.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json';
Vue.$http = Axios;

// When making request.
Vue.$http[action](url, payload, { withCredentials: true }).then(() => // Handle request);
```

You can see from the image that the cookie is being sent on the logout request.

[image]

When logging out I'm hitting this endpoint and destroying the session [as is explained on the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessiondestroycallback).

```js
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  try {
    req.session.destroy(() => {
      return responses.responseWithResultAsync(res); // Helper method that logs and returns status code 200.
    });

    return responses.handleErrorAsync(res); // Helper method that logs and returns status code 500.
  } catch (error) {
    return responses.handleErrorAsync(res, error); // Helper method that logs and returns status code 500.
  }
});
```

The interesting thing is that the session on the DB is removed so I know that the cookie is being sent properly on the request with the right session ID but it is not removing it on the browser for some reason. After logging out I still have this:

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I find it odd that the session is being removed on the DB successfully but not on the request.

Comment: That's how the lib works, it does not delete the cookie: https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/241

Comment: Thanks, @RolandStarke, I wasn't aware of that. So the only solution is to manually remove the cookie in some other way?

Comment: You can just catch 401 on FE-side and redirect to a login page and after successful login you'll get a new `connect.sid` cookie

Comment: But why do you need to worry about this? If the cookie is deleted on the DB side, the user won't be able to login anymore.

Comment: @AvivLo, for some reason, if I don't remove the cookie from the browser after logging out, subsequent attempts to login with Microsoft will eventually fail.

Comment: Because it expires

Comment: @AvivLo Yes, but even if it expired, if I tried to login afterwards the expired cookie should be replaced with a valid session cookie. Instead the whole thing stops working until the cookie is either manually removed on the dev tools or by closing the browser.

Comment: But when you set a new cookie the old ones should be replaced no? But this question is solved right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RolandStarke mentioned the express-session library [doesn't have the built in functionality to remove the cookie from the browser](http://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/241), so I just did it manually in the following way:

```js
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.session && req.session.cookie) {
      res.cookie('connect.sid', null, {
        expires: new Date('Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC'),
        httpOnly: true,
      });

      req.session.destroy((error) => {
        if (error) {
          return responses.handleErrorAsync(res, error);
        }

        return responses.responseWithResultAsync(res);
      });
    }

    return responses.responseWithResultAsync(res);
  } catch (error) {
    return responses.handleErrorAsync(res, error);
  }
});
```